# Exchange 2007 Replacing ö with oe

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

First, I have seen http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822447 and gone through the steps (with the exception of the replace string, as that seems like more of a work around than an actual solution).

I couldn't find any .net installed with the exception of KB958488, which I uninstalled and reinstalled after changing the regional settings.

We have two Exchange 2007 servers running on a Windows 2003 server and Windows 2008R2 server. This issue only effects mailboxes running on the Windows 2008R2 server.

As said, I have changed the regional settings to Swedish, made sure it is copied to all accounts, reinstalled the only trace of .net I could find and still have made no progress.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Edit:
As pointed out this is a little unclear.

Simply put, exchange is adding email addresses as follows:

Ingmar Bergström gets both ingmar.bergstrom@example.com and ingmar.bergstroem@example.com

The "oe" that is replacing "ö" is incorrect and unwanted, it should simply be o (which is the behavior on the other server).

I just realized I pasted the wrong link in the window!

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948212

Comment: You might want to clarify what you're trying to achieve. Based on what you've written so far we don't actually know what you're trying to do

Comment: It just came to my attention that I did not remove .net 3.5 through "Features" under server manager. Could this be the issue? My service window is rapidly closing so I don't have time to test it right now.

Comment: @MarkHenderson Added a bit more info at the bottom.

Comment: Much better now. Unfortunately I can't help :(

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug to me.  Have you tried building another 2k3 server and verified that it affects only 2k8?  If so I'd suggest contacting Microsoft.

Comment: Installing another 2003 server isn't really an option, however I could potentially reinstall 2k8 and ensure that the region settings are correct from the outset. It will be a while before I have time for that....

Answer (score 0):

Seems like after changing the regional settings and reinstalling .net the issue is resolved for all new accounts, however not for accounts that have already encountered the issue (which I suppose is best as they have sent out a few emails with the oe address instead of the o address). The issue is resolved enough, as the o address is now the default for all users with ö in the name.

In short, the kb article did fix it, I was just tired and impatient.